# Using plt.text to only plot data that meets a certain criteria

Tags: python

I run a script that retrieves data from lines of html code. I then plot this data on a map. Right now, I use the following script to plot all of the numbers I retrieve on the map, where c.high0 is the number I pulled from the html script.

```
for c in cities :
    c.retrieveTemps()
    long, lat = c.long, c.lat
    x, y = map(float(long), float(lat))
    plt.text(x, y, c.high0, fontsize=7, fontweight='bold')
```

This works just as it should, however, I only want to plot the numbers if they are >= 34. Is there anyway to do this, perhaps within the plt.text line? I am stumped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
for c in cities :
    c.retrieveTemps()
    long, lat = c.long, c.lat
    x, y = map(float(long), float(lat))
    if c.high0 >= 34:
        plt.text(x, y, c.high0, fontsize=7, fontweight='bold')
```

If you really need to do it inside the plt line:

```
plt.text(x, y, c.high0 if c.high0 >= 34 else '', fontsize=7, fontweight='bold')
```

Comment: oh I assumed c.high0 was a number and not a string! anyway glad to hear it worked.